# SQL query against an array?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any kind of php library to execute SQL queries agains arrays?

Something like this:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        "field_a" => "first_a"      
        "field_b" => "something"        
    ),
    array(
        "field_a" => "second_a"     
        "field_b" => "else"     
    ),
    array(
        "field_a" => "third_a"      
        "field_b" => "something"        
    )
);

$rows = arrayQuery($array, "SELECT field_a WHERE field_b = 'something'");

/*
$rows = array(
    array(
        "field_a" => "first_a"      
    ),
    array(
        "field_a" => "third_a"      
    )
);
 */
```

Found something similar: http://blog.phpdeveloper.org/?p=61, but that is not a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that [LINQ for PHP](http://phplinq.codeplex.com/) would do the trick. I think this is a close as it gets to 'querying arrays' in PHP.